# How to specify dateTimeValue="4th Nov,2012 1:59 AM" is EDT while parsing DateTimeOffset(dateTimeValue)

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert system time zone to `CST`

I am parsing the date `"11/4/2012 1:59 AM"` using `DateTimeOffset.Parse(dateTimeValue);`

after parsing it to json, I want

My expected serialized object should be

```
"DateTime": "/Date(1352008785000)/",
"OffsetMinutes": -300
```

How do i set offset explicitly to get -300 in offset minutes

Can someone help me?

Comment: Have a look on this page: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/cst Here it says the offset is 6 hours.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing daylight savings time. There is a reason why system time zones always come with cities where they are valid. There can be some areas in a time zone that observe DST and some that don't. So the statement *"I've set the system time zone to CST."* is ambiguous. If you are using CST without switch to the DST time (CDT), the offset will remain the same throughout the year.

Comment: tzutil /s "Central Standard Time" command is used to switch to central time zone. how to switch to DST time?

Comment: @Shilpa: You don't switch to DST time. At certain dates in the year (during summer and most of spring and autumn), DST applies. In the rest of the year, standard time applies. Whether DST is observed is a property of the time zone.